# Dropd down tabs or drop down menus beneath ActionBar in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, drop-down-menu

My need is to add a drop down menu like the one shown in attached image link.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJQJo.jpg

I don't know what to be used, whether it is tabs or menus. My need is when I press the last tab/menu, the sub menu should be shown and I could be able to handle the corresponding actions. Even when I handle those menus, I should be able to show the top tab/ menu without interruption.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ActionBar with tab-navigation-mode and if the last tab is clicked you could simply trigger a [PopupMenu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#PopupMenu) (even though this seems a little weird and is not what I expect to happen when I click tab).

Answer (score 0):

It's called as overflow menus. Look this example, you will get an idea.

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/adding-action-items-and-overflow-menu-items-to-action-bar-in-android/

And nice explanation been given here. http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/1249 and for source code.ref here: https://github.com/StylingAndroid/StylingActionBar/Tree/StylingPart2

Comment: And important to note that action bar will support for above api level 11 and not for below versions ie below 3.0. So to support in all version you must go for action bar sherlock.

Comment: But, the code given above creates menu within the action bar. Is it possible to add the menu like tabs below the action bar ?